# Creating web hosting in a laptop

Tags: web-hosting, dns, apache

I was searching Google for how I can configure my webdoamin registered with GoDaddy and static IP I have obtained from Mumbai ISP.

I have seen one question which was asked three years before in which a person asked how he can change IP address to web domain.

I have done the following:

- Downloaded and configured Apache 2.4.23, MySQL 5.7 64bit, PHP 7.0.10
- I have entered port number in Listen
- Entered Server name as `www.example.com` which I registered with GoDaddy

At GoDaddy domain DNS management:

- I have created `@` as host and assigned static IP assigned by my ISP
- I have also assigned IPV6 address for AAAA record and assigned host name as `@`

But when I typed my domain in browser it says we can not find the said domain.

I have also pinged with my static IP, it shows 100% lost, ping with web domain, it shows 100% loss. I have D-Link 2730U router, which web address is `192.168.1.1`, I have port forwarding for TCP and UDP for port 8000, I have selected from select list for server name as Web Server (HTTP). At server IP address I have mentioned static IP provided by my ISP.

Can anybody tell me what could be the mistake? What next I have to do?

Comment: You will not be able to ping an IP address on the WAN side of your router from the LAN side of things. That is simply not how it works. As well, you have to give it time for the domain name to propagate out through the Internet. This can take anywhere from 1-72 hours depending upon the ISP. It is best that whatever computer you are using to ping and do nslookup on uses an external DNS. Your ISP DNS should be okay. You can always use something like http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ from outside your network to check for a status. Please let us know where you stand.

Comment: Rather than ping use `nmap -p 80 YOU-EXTERNAL-IP-ADDRESS-HERE`, if you get a response, then you need to wait from 1-72 hours as suggested.

Comment: Often overlooked is opening the port in your OS's firewall. Check to make sure you have port `8000` as rule/exception for Apache, then check to see if your public IP is reachable via `http://<public_ip>:8000`, and confirm you have port forwarding setup correctly in your router. Be sure to delete your DNS cache so it updates, and using a traceroute can help to narrow down where the loss occurs.

Answer (score 1):

**I would do the following.**

**Use whatsmydns.net to see how your records are propagating**. (I am not affiliated with whatsmydns.net)

**Make sure your router is indeed forwarding to your computer's ip address** IE: 192.168.1.x

**Make sure your DNS A record does point to your local IP address** by typing WhatsMYIp into a search bar (ie Google > https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=whatismyipaddress )

Assuming you have your Apache directory info right, after ensuring the said above is correct, all should work fine. I use this method when developing locally and allowing clients to view sites before going live on their servers.